# Wordpress - Media Library - SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am attempting to remove 20,000 media files and all DB references from my Wordpress site.

I found some SQL statements but none of them work. There is a syntax error. I'm not an SQL expert.

Here is what I have. Any insight would be great.

```
DELETE FROM 'wpsq_posts' WHERE 'post_type' = "attachment" AND 'post_date' BETWEEN '2023-03-04 00:00:00' and '2023-03-04 23:59:00';
DELETE FROM 'wpsq_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = "_wp_attached_file" AND 'post_date' BETWEEN '2023-03-04 00:00:00' and '2023-03-04 23:59:00';
DELETE FROM 'wpsq_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = "_wp_attachment_metadata" AND 'post_date' BETWEEN '2023-03-04 00:00:00' and '2023-03-04 23:59:00';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No quotes (or double quotes) around object names like tables and columns. Single quotes around string literals/values like `attachment` or `_wp_attached_file`. So your first SQL statement should look like

```
DELETE FROM wpsq_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_date BETWEEN '2023-03-04 00:00:00' and '2023-03-04 23:59:00';
```

I would also HIGHLY suggest running the following statement first to see that the records returns are, in fact, the ones you want to delete. Then say a little prayer, throw some salt over your shoulder, back up your table to a file just to be extra sure, say another prayer, wait 30 minutes, and then run the `DELETE` statement, have a panic attack, check the table once again, and hopefully breathe a sigh of relief. At least, that's my usual process.

```
SELECT * FROM wbsq_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_date BETWEEN '2023-03-04 00:00:00' and '2023-03-04 23:59:00';
```